# AJAX Post posts, but not until I refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having some issues with an AJAX POST request to an mLab database of mine. Basically, I've got a 'chartJS' chart on my page that is responding to data I add to my database. If I run my PUT function to update a single document, everything works just fine, and my chart updates accordingly immediately. Yet, when I run nearly identical code in my POST function (changing the type to "POST" instead of "PUT", the POST never seems to complete until I refresh the page, at which time it my chart reflects the POSTed data accurately and completely.

I'm very new to all of this programming stuff, but it seems to me that the data is getting posted, but the POST response is getting stuck in limbo until I manually abort it by refreshing - maybe?

My code is at https://github.com/TheScogg/lifelogs if needed. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```js
function post() {
  jQuery.get("/db/", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("Get response:");
    // console.dir(data);
    // console.log(textStatus);
    // console.dir(jqXHR);
  }).done(function (data) {
    console.log("==========================================")
    console.log(sendInfo.activities);
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/db/",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        date: sendInfo.date,
        activities: JSON.stringify(sendInfo.activities),
        survey: JSON.stringify(sendInfo.survey)
      },
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        getData();
      }
    });
  }).done(function (data) {
    console.log("put date loaded");
  });
}


function put(idMatch) {
  console.log("Duplicate Date at id: " + idMatch);

  jQuery.get("/db/" + idMatch, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("Get response:");
    // console.dir(data);
    // console.log(textStatus);
    // console.dir(jqXHR);
  }).done(function (data) {
    console.log("==========================================")
    console.log(sendInfo.activities);
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/db/" + idMatch,
      type: "PUT",
      data: {
        date: sendInfo.date,
        activities: JSON.stringify(sendInfo.activities),
        survey: JSON.stringify(sendInfo.survey)
      },
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        getData();
      }
    });
  }).done(function (data) {
    console.log("put date loaded");
  });
}

// Reload chart after POSTING/PUTTING NEW RECORD
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network tab. I suspect you have a server side error and can tell by the response status (500= server errror)

Comment: In the Firebug network tab, it spins for a few minutes, and then returns status "Aborted". Now, in Chrome, running POST locks the browser up entirely. But when I close Chrome and open it again, it's showing the data that I POSTed just fine.

Comment: My guess is something is wrong in your server code. What language is it and can you debug it?

Comment: I'm using Node. And, at this point in my knowledge, my knowledge of debugging is kind of confined to trial and error.

Comment: Well trying doing some logging to console in node within the various steps of updating the db . If problem isn't there we don't know what `getData()` does and it also seems strange that you need nested ajax to do this post

Comment: I think you gave me something to think about talking about nested AJAX. Up above I have the following code. It searches through my database to see if I have already posted a document with a given date, and determines whether to do a POST request with a new document, or a PUT request updating a second document. So, I essentially have a POST request nested inside a GET request. If I isolate the POST request and put it outside this GET request, it works fine.

Comment: $.get("/db/", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var isMatch = false;
            data.forEach(function (val) {
                // If new date and existing date match, pass id (idMatch) to function (put)
                if (val.date == sendInfo.date) {
                    isMatch = true;
                    idMatch = (val._id);
                }
            });

            if (!isMatch) {post();} else {put(idMatch);}
        });

Comment: OK..that logic might make sense. Another way is to see if a property like `id` exists on the object itself and use that to determine whether to post or put

Comment: Welp, now I'm back to the POST not working, even on it's own again. I appreciate the help man. I'll post back if I ever figure anything out.

Comment: learn to use console.log() in node console...might help

Answer (score 0):

**charlietfl**, thank you so much for helping to talk me through this. I found my mistake - and believe me when I say it was a noob mistake.

I had various code in various files that had post requests to the same place. For example, I was playing with code down at the bottom of a file called app.js. However, I also had code trying to post to the same place in a file called './routes/index'. Well, guess what I realized was at the top of my app.js file?

var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);

So, it was pulling a POST request that I had forgotten that I had even created before it even got to the POST request that I thought I was sending.

Also, I had various backup files, that in retrospect, had similar code that it may have been trying to use.

Long story short, I need to go back through my studies and really try to understand how everything relates to each other in an Express project, and really try to understand the where's and why's of everything.

Thanks again!